# Is there a way to wrap protocol buffers into Objective-C and still take advantage of inheritance?

Tags: objective-c, protocol-buffers, objective-c++

I want to use Protocol Buffers in an iOS project. I'm trying to avoid making the whole project into an Objective-C++ fiasco, so I want to wrap the C++ protobuf classes into Objective-C ones. I have several dozen protobuf messages, and while I have done this successfully one class at a time, ideally I would like to use inheritance to minimize the repeated code. I'm new to Objective-C and I haven't used what little I knew of C++ in 10 years, so this has mostly been an exercise in frustration. Below is an example of how I have wrapped a single message.

**Code**

.proto:

```
message MessageA {
    optional string value = 1;
}
```

MessageAWrapper.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface MessageAWrapper : NSObject

@property (nonatomic) NSString *value;

+ (id)fromString:(NSString *)string;
- (NSString *)serialize;

@end
```

MessageAWrapper.mm:

```
#import "MessageA.h"
#import "message.pb.h"

@interface MessageAWrapper ()

@property (nonatomic) MessageA *message;

@end

@implementation MessageAWrapper

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.message = new MessageA();
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    delete self.message;
    self.message = NULL;
}

- (NSString *)value {
    return [NSString stringWithUTF8String:self.message->value().c_str()];
}

- (void)setValue:(NSString *)value {
   self.message->set_value([value UTF8String]);
}

- (NSString *)serialize {
    std::string output;
    self.message->SerializeToString(&output);
    return [NSString stringWithUTF8String:output.c_str()];
}

+ (id)fromString:(NSString *)string {
    MessageA *message = new MessageA();
    message->ParseFromString([string UTF8String]);

    MessageAWrapper *wrapper = [[MessageAWrapper alloc] init];
    wrapper.message = message;
    return wrapper;
}

@end
```

**Goal**

There is a lot of code here that will be repeated dozens of times in which the only variation is the wrapped class type (`init`, `dealloc`, `serialize`, `fromString`), so ideally I would like to put it on a parent `ProtobufMesssage` class instead. Unfortunately I've had no success in making this work because I can't find a way for the parent class to know the class its children are using, which is required for example in `init` and `fromString`.

**Things I've attempted**

- struct
- template class
- void*

**Obstacles I've encountered**

- can't find a way to store a reference to a class/type
- can't have any C++ headers or code in the .h file (as this requires the whole project to be Objective-C++)
- difficulty keeping references to the protobuf message parents (`Message` or `MessageLite`) because they are abstract

As I said I have very little understanding of C++ or Objective-C; most of my experience is with much higher level languages like Python and Java (though I do mostly understand basic C things like pointers).

Is this perhaps not even possible? Am I approaching it wrong or missing something obvious? Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about C++ at all, but can't you declare the Objective-C property to be a `Message *`?

You've already separated the C++ code from the header by declaring the property in the .mm file, the problem you will have is with instance methods named by the compiler (`value()` and `set_value()`) and only being valid methods for the subclass. It might help to use the `Reflection` class to get and set fields by their name. Here is an excerpt from Google's `message.h` showing this:

```
Message* foo = new Foo;
const Descriptor* descriptor = foo->GetDescriptor();

const FieldDescriptor* text_field = descriptor->FindFieldByName("text");
assert(text_field != NULL);
assert(text_field->type() == FieldDescriptor::TYPE_STRING);
assert(text_field->label() == FieldDescriptor::LABEL_OPTIONAL);

const Reflection* reflection = foo->GetReflection();
assert(reflection->GetString(foo, text_field) == "Hello World!");
```

You could create Objective-C `-objectForKey:` and `-setObject:forKey:` instance methods that typecheck and get or set the value (confusingly, the key in the case of `MessageAWrapper` would be `@"value"`). Your subclasses would not even need to be aware of the C++ code.

You can also separate the creator function in `-init` and `+fromString:` method into something like, `+_createNewInstance`;

```
+(Message*)_createNewInstance{ return new MessageA(); }
```

allowing your subclasses of `MessageWrapper` to reuse all code except for creating the C++ object.

Answer (score 0):

While Objective C has very powerful instrospection capabilities, C++ is more limited. You do have [RTTI](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C++_Programming/RTTI) (Run time type information), but it's not even as powerful as the Objective C counterpart.

However, it might be enough for you. Within your Objective C++ class, you might find the type of you message object with the typeid operator:

```
if( (typeid(self.message) == typed(foo)){
  //doSomething
else if( (typeid(self.message) == typed(bar)){
  // doSomething else
}
```

Maybe the best option is to add another indirection level. Make an Objective C class hierarchy that wraps all your protocol buffer C++ classes and then create another Objective C that uses those classes (as delegates maybe). I believe this might be a better option. Use C++ only for those unavoidable cases.

Good luck!

Comment: using `dynamic_cast` would be better